# can react storefront pwa of moovweb deploy other then moovweb xdn

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, storefront, moovweb, react-storefront

On Moovweb landing page they mention
**No vendor lock-in**
under Built for Developers section
 
https://www.moovweb.com/

but in documentation they have guide of deployment only on 
Moovweb XDN 
https://pwa.moovweb.com/v5.6.3/guides/deploy 
is it possible to deploy other then moovweb xdn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guide to running React Storefront apps in Express:

https://pwa.moovweb.com/guides/express

Comment: thank you very much can you tell me about this issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626007/how-to-start-react-storefront-moovweb-on-express-server

Answer (score 1):

The latest boilerplate and starter app contain npm scripts to run in express (i.e. `start:express`).

Comment: thank you very much can you tell me about this issue ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626007/how-to-start-react-storefront-moovweb-on-express-server