# How to start react storefront (moovweb) on express server

Tags: reactjs, express, storefront, moovweb, react-storefront

On official Documentation server start with 
 
**npm run start:express** 
Or 
**yarn start:express**  
This is documentation link 
https://pwa.moovweb.com/guides/express

**Error Log**

```
exports = module.exports = createDebug.debug = createDebug['default'] = createDebug;
^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'
```

**On build/server/main.js:51875**

> please help me to solve this problem

Comment: On start:express command app built first and then serve as a build. so  `issue is in build`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with the starter app that create-react-storefront was building a while ago.  This has been fixed.  Express should work fine now when you create a new app.